# jquery extra full calendar use loop to set events dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, model

I want to load all events on extra_full-calender using only jquery

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var listRdv= [[${listRdv}]];
</script>
```

**i do loop its work**

```
 $(function() {
     $.each(listRdv, function(index,value){
     alert(value.date);});
 });
```

**but Result is like this: doesn't work**

```
var events=[
   $.each(listRdv, function(index,value){
         {
            title: value.titleRdv,
            color: value.colorRdv
         }             
   )};
];
```

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. `value.title` and `value.libelle` are obviously not the same properties. COuld you explain a little bit better?

Comment: I think the character ' after value.date is causing errors. What happens if you remove them and do the properties title and date exist?

Comment: @Shilly look at again to script i've changed it ,

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the problem. I don't understand the `th:inline` syntax and have no idea what `var listRdv= [[${listRdv}]];` is supposed to be. AS written listRdv is an array with objects that have to contain a date, titleRdv and colorRdv property. Neither of which I can see in the rest of the code.

Comment: i have here error
  var events=[
 $.each(listRdv, function(index,value){
         {
          title: value.titleRdv,
          color: value.colorRdv
            )
  )};
];

Comment: did you solve question?

Comment: @hasan yes 
 var events=[];
  $.map( listRdv, function( r ) {
   //alert(r.libelle);
   events.push({
          title: r.libelle,
             start: '2017-06-12',
              textColor:"#E57373"
         });
     });